# 10's complement of a number statement

Tags: bit-manipulation, cpu-architecture, twos-complement, complement

> The values of a,x,y if 47x80 is the 10's complement of yaya0 is:

I calculated the 10's complement of yaya0 to be 100,000-yaya0 and then.

```
   47x80=100,000-yaya0
```

Now how to find values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
47080 + 100x = 100000 - (10000y + 1000a + 100y + 10a)
52920 = 100x + 10100y + 1010a
```

==> `a = 2` otherwise you won`t get the 2 as tens

```
50900 = 100x + 10100y
```

this can be split up in `5 = y` and `9 = x + y`

so

```
a = 2
x = 4
y = 5
```

Comment: because a, x and y are digits, the only possibility to get the 20 in 52920 is that a=2. You also could compare the digits in the second line and get: 5 = y, 2 = a, 9 = x+y, 2 = a and 0 = 0.

Answer (score 0):

47x80 represents a number where 'x' is the hundreds. So does yaya0 where 'y' represent the 10-thousands and the hundreds and 'a' represents the thousands and the tens.

The rest is obvious.

Comment: What's the '0' here/Won't  it make all the term equal to 'zero'?

Comment: Wouldn't it be 47x80=y^2*a^2*0(all term becomes zero then?)

Comment: It isn't multiplication, it is a number representation in decimal. 4,7,x,8,0 are digits as also a,y,0.