# binary conversion using 3 figures system 0,1,2

Tags: binary, decimal, number-systems

> Suppose  system is evolved by extraterrestrial creatures having only 3 figures and they use the figures 0,1,2 with (2>1>0) ,How to represent the binary equivalent of 222 using this?

I calculated it to be  `22020` but the book answers it 11010 .how this.Shouldn't i use the same method to binary conversion as from decimal to binary except using '3' here ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant base 3 (not binary) equivalent of decimal 222

```
22020 in base 3 is 222 in decimal.
220202(your answer) in base 3 is 668 in decimal.
11010 (according to book) in base 3 is 111 in decimal.

222 in binary is 11011110
```

May be i will be able to tell where you went wrong if you tell the method you used to calculate base 3 equivalent of 222

**Edit:**
Sorry I could not understand the problem until you provide the [link](http://books.google.com.pk/books?id=MQmOP7GTxeoC&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=Suppose%20system%20is%20evolved%20by%20extraterrestrial%20creatures%20having%20only%203%20figures%20and%20they%20use%20the%20figures%200,1,2%20with%20(2%3E1%3E0)&source=bl&ots=Ol5TPdfshR&sig=1SHQXH7slUuku9lkzUg5mX7eoCE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AhxrVJK-EcHmaPXCgOgC&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Suppose%20system%20is%20evolved%20by%20extraterrestrial%20creatures%20having%20only%203%20figures%20and%20they%20use%20the%20figures%200%2C1%2C2%20with%20(2%3E1%3E0)&f=false). It says what is binary equivalent of 222 (remember 222 is in base 3)

```
222 in base 3 = 26 in decimal (base 10)
26 in decimal = 11010 in binary
```

Mark it as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: i edited post i too calculated `22020' but it was a typo

Comment: Yes u r rite..but what's the answer to my question? @Ashwani Dausodia

Comment: Can we infer from the answer of book `11010` as to what was done?

Comment: What I can say is that they printed `1` instead of `2`

Comment: You may see the question here,http://books.google.com.pk/books?id=MQmOP7GTxeoC&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=Suppose+system+is+evolved+by+extraterrestrial+creatures+having+only+3+figures+and+they+use+the+figures+0,1,2+with+(2>1>0)&source=bl&ots=Ol5TPdfshR&sig=1SHQXH7slUuku9lkzUg5mX7eoCE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AhxrVJK-EcHmaPXCgOgC&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Suppose%20system%20is%20evolved%20by%20extraterrestrial%20creatures%20having%20only%203%20figures%20and%20they%20use%20the%20figures%200%2C1%2C2%20with%20(2%3E1%3E0)&f=false

Comment: if u don't mind kindly have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947908/10s-complement-of-a-number-statement/26948309?noredirect=1#comment42440008_26948309

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the start is decimal 222.

Well, without knowing the system used in the book I would decompose it by hand in the following way:

```
3^4 = 81,
3^3 = 27,
3^2 = 9,
3^1 = 3,
```

So 81 fits twize into 222 , so the 4th "bit" has the value 2.
Remaining are 60. 27 fits twice into 60 so the next bit is 2 again.
Remaining are 6. 9 fits not into 6, so the next bit is 0.
Remaining are 6. 3 fits twice into 6, so the next bit is 2.
remaining are 0. so the last bit 0

This gives as result 22020.

One quick sanity check on how many "bits" are needed for representation of decimal 222 in a number system with 3 Numbers: 1+log(222)/log(3)=5,9 => nearly 6 "bits" are needed, which goes well with the result 22020.

Answer (score 0):

First see how many figures you have, here we have **3** so
we have to convert 222 to binary when we have only 3 figures so

> 2×3^2+2×3^1+2×3^0 (if the number were being 121 then →
> 1×3^2+2×3^1+1×3^0)

which gives 26 then divide this with 2 until we don't get 1/2
when reminder is 1 then write 1 if 0 then 0 you will get

so we get 01011 just reverse it we have the answer
**11010**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwTRd.png)